# NLog 4.0 unable to connect to SQL Server named instance to log to database table

Tags: nlog

I am using NLog to log errors from a Winform .NET application to a file and database table. The database table is hosted on SQL Server 2014.

The NLog config file is show below.  Logs are successfully written to the file.

I can successfully log to a database table with the exact same config file if SQL Server is installed as a default instance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" internalLogFile="Nlog.log">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${logger}|${threadid}|${windows-identity:domain=false}--${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*" fileName="My.Application.log" />
    <target name="database" type="Database">
      <connectionString>Data Source=ABC\DEV01;Initial Catalog=my_database;User Id=user01;Password=Password01;Application Name=My Application;Failover Partner=XYZ\DEV01</connectionString>
      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO tb_system_logging(log_date,log_level,log_logger,log_message,log_machine_name, log_user_name, log_call_site, log_thread, log_exception, log_stacktrace) VALUES(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message, @machinename, @user_name, @call_site, @threadid,
        @log_exception, @stacktrace);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@machinename" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}" />
      <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
      <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception}" />
      <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" appendTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I see the following error logged to the internal log file NLog.Log when I run the application on my development server that also host the SQL Server instance.

```
2015-08-25 23:41:27.0999 Error Error when writing to database System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

I have checked that SQL Server allows remote connections and TCP/IP and named pipe protocols are enabled on the server.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards

James

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. NLog even writes log to the database, its just occasionally throws this error. Did you happen to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your connectionstring. Maybe this is helpful: [how to solve the system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875730/how-to-solve-the-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904-error)

Comment: This error is really strange because the exact same configuration file works with a default instance.  My development workstation is running Windows 10 and SQL server 2014 Developer Edition not sure if that might be related.