# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string C# application

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion

I am trying to return DB records who have birthdays that are on the current date. I am currently running into a conversion error.

Here is the code And I am using varchar for `DOB` on my database. Please I need help.

```
string query = @"SELECT Names, FamilyName, PhoneNo, gender, DOB, Email 
FROM Members 
WHERE month(Members.DOB) = month(getdate()) 
  AND day(Members.DOB) = day(getdate())";
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875730/how-to-solve-the-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904-error)

Comment: Does the same query work in something like SSMS? Why are you using varchar for a date when there are several date/time types to choose from?

Comment: I downvoted because there was no effort to formulate the question properly.

Comment: The query worked earlier with SSMS and I even created a view for it. But right now its no longer working. And it seems that is where the issue is coming from.

Comment: I really need help on this. Its a school project for me and I have been stocked for weeks. I need to be able to retrieve members having their birthday at a click of a button.

Comment: “I am using Varchar for DOB on my database”. That's your problem, store dates as `DateTime`, not `VarChar`.

Comment: @okurujoe -  share some sample data from Members.DOB column, would like to see the format of date.

Comment: It works well with DateTime but then I will have issue inserting data to my table.

Comment: It used to work but now it doesn't. This begs the question "what did you change?" Treat dates as dates instead of strings.

Comment: “I will have issue inserting data to my table”? Then you're inserting data into your table wrong. Storing dates as strings is causing second-order damage all over your application. You have to stop doing that.

Comment: I think I will just change the datatype in my database

Answer (score 0):

You have to format **Members.DOB** to `DateTime`, something like:

```
Cast(Members.DOB as DateTime)
```

So the full expression would be:

```
Where month(Cast(Members.DOB as DateTime)) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because you are trying to call `Month` and `YEAR` functions for varchar datatype column `Members.DOB`. You should convert this column value to `datetime` in the `where` clause -

```
string query = @"SELECT Names, FamilyName, PhoneNo, gender, DOB, Email 
FROM Members 
WHERE month(convert(datetime,Members.DOB,105)) = month(getdate()) 
  AND day(convert(datetime,Members.DOB,105)) = day(getdate())";
```

in the above conversion, third parameter `105` is the format of date value in DOB column, style code `105` represents `dd-mm-yyyy` format, you can find more style codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Comment: When I try this, Its gives an error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: share the sample date value in DOB column

Comment: `birthday = (metroComboBoxday.SelectedIndex + 1) + "-" + (metroComboBoxmonth.SelectedItem) + "-" + txtyear.Text; `  This is how I get my birthday, that is why I use string to datatype. The same data value _1980-05-01_

Comment: try the updated query with style code 105 now. You can try different style codes from the link that i have shared