# SQL Server Disconnect

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help with such error?

> CheckHMFireTime: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A
>   transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout
>   period has expired.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The semaphore timeout period has expired

Answer (score -1):

Try these links

1. support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325487
2. stackoverflow.com/questions/551282/semaphore-timeout-period

This may be usefull

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure that,the sql server is up & running
- check your connection string , whether it has any spelling mistakes  - 
  [How to solve the system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875730/how-to-solve-the-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904-error)